# How to fix tables with different lengths

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, confusion-matrix

First I am a newbie to R (less than two months) and first time asking a question here so I apologize if I do not include all is needed.

I am trying to create a confusion matrix from a random forest using:

```
library (randomForest)
library (caret)
rfSeg1 <- randomForest(desc ~ Seg1, data= roi_dataSeg1, importance= TRUE, mtry = 4, ntree= 500, trControl = rfSeg1Control, tuneGrid = rfSeg1Grid,metric = "Kappa", maximize = true, na.action=na.exclude)

conftbl <- confusionMatrix(rfSeg1$predicted,roi_dataSeg1$desc)
```

I was successful using this with a different input data set however fails with new data inputs.  I have to create a table with Sensitivity, Specificity, PPV, NPV etc. by class for each study boundary.  I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
>   all arguments must have the same length
> ```

I ran:

```
> identical(levels(rfSeg1$predicted),levels(roi_dataSeg1$desc))
[1] TRUE
> identical(length(rfSeg1$predicted),length(roi_dataSeg1$desc))
[1] FALSE
> length(roi_dataSeg1$desc)
[1] 152242
> length(rfSeg1$predicted)
[1] 151567
```

I have looked online and tried several things but to no avail.  Any help will be greatly appreciated to fix this error.

Comment: your data has different lengths. `R` logic is mostly vector based. Therefore it throws you an error if you try to use two vectors with different length.

Comment: Your problem is that you excluded the `NA`-values. Assign all `NA`s to a vector: `noNA<-((is.na(roi_dataSeg1$desc)+is.na(roi_dataSeg1$Seg1))==0)`Use `roi_dataSeg1$desc[noNA]` instead of `roi_dataSeg1$desc`.

Comment: Perfect using the code you provided worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that the code I provided is very much `R`-logic. Actually `apply(roi_dataSeg1[,c('Seg1','desc')],1,function(x) sum(is.na(x))==0)` might be easier to understand if you want to move on up to the apply-family. However I only recommend learning `lapply` and `sapply`, because they are both damn fast. They are faster than everything else in `R` except `Rcpp`-Code.

Comment: I looked at lapply but ran into additional errors and did not pursue.  I will add  the apply code as I have to run this model 4 more times.  I tried leaving off the na.action=na.exclude in the random forest code but it too gave errors,  Do you recommend keeping that code and using apply for future work or try to eliminate the need to use na.action=na.exclude in random forest.

Comment: You need to exclude NAs for tree models. Oh now that you mention it I have a third suggestion `noNA<-unlist(lapply(1:nrow(roi_dataSeg1),function(j) sum(is.na(roi_dataSeg1[j,c('Seg1','desc')]))))`. If you want to know which of the three suggested ways is fastest do a [microbenchmark](https://www.r-bloggers.com/microbenchmarking-with-r/)

Comment: I ran the model again with a different dataset and used noNA<-((is.na(roi_dataSeg2$desc)+is.na(roi_dataSeg2$Seg2))==0)         But getting this message:      Warning message:
In is.na(roi_dataSeg2$Seg2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'         If I proceed with the  conftbl <- confusionMatrix(rfSeg2$predicted,roi_dataSeg2$desc[noNA]),  I get the error  Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) :
  all arguments must have the same length.  I am not sure what is going on as I was trying to reproduce your fix using a different data set as input to the model.

Comment: Here is some more info > identical(levels(rfSeg2$predicted),levels(roi_dataSeg2$desc))
[1] TRUE
> identical(length(rfSeg2$predicted),length(roi_dataSeg2$desc))
[1] FALSE
> length(rfSeg2$predicted)
[1] 264779
> length(roi_dataSeg2$desc)
[1] 265582